# How do I call a function which is in replicated storage

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to give the players different weapons based on what team they are on. I'm trying to do this via creating a instance string value and adding it to a folder which is the player's name in ReplicatedStorage, But it only gets updated on the Player's side, Not for the server. I'm trying to fix this via making a script in ReplicatedStorage and calling the function named `handleTeams` but I always get the error which says that `handleTeams` is not the child of the script.

LocalScript (LocalScript) (Players > Player1 > PlayerGui > InsertedObjects > team > Russia)

```
local p = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    game.Players[p].TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Really blue")
    game.Workspace[p].Humanoid.Health = 0
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Enabled = false
    
    local Player = Instance.new("Folder")
    local GameTag = Instance.new("StringValue")
    GameTag.Value = "USA"
    GameTag.Name = "TeamName"


    Player.Name = game.Players:FindFirstChild(p).Name
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ReplicatedStorage.Script(Player, GameTag)

end)
```

TeamGear (Script) (Workspace > TeamGear)

```
function onSpawned(plr) 
    if script.Parent.Parent.ReplicatedStorage.Teams[plr.Name].TeamName == "Russia" then
        local tools = script.Parent.Parent.Teams.Russia:GetChildren()
        for _,c in pairs(tools) do 
            c:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack 
        end 
    end
    if script.Parent.Parent.ReplicatedStorage.Teams[plr.Name].TeamName == "USA" then
        local tools = script.Parent.Parent.Teams.USA:GetChildren()
        for _,c in pairs(tools) do 
            c:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack 
        end 
    end
end
```

Script (Script) (ReplicatedStorage > Script)

```
function handleTeams(player, tag)
    player.Parent = script.Parent.Teams
    tag.Parent = player
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define a script in `ReplicatedStorage` that can be called from other scripts, it has to be a `ModuleScript`.

For example if you want to have a script in `ReplicatedStorage` that prints "Hello World", then you'd create a `ModuleScript` (not a Script) like this:

`ReplicatedStorage > ModuleScript`

```
local module = {}

function module.Hello()
    print("Hello, World!")
end

return module
```

Then from a LocalScript or Script you can call it like so:

```
local HelloModule = require(game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("ModuleScript"))
HelloModule.Hello()
```